# Vertical scroll animation to certain content on the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, media-queries

I have a rotating site that goes to different page.  Those pages will be on a tv monitor, and will overflow in height.  I would like to use a vertical scroll plugin that determines the last piece of content within the viewport and scrolls to that portion making it to the top.  Once the bottom of the page is reached, a redirect to a new page will be made and process repeats.  Is there a plugin out there that handles that, or a simple solution?

Below if the viewport gets cut off at the third game div, then it would scroll to that div moving it to the top.

```
<div class="game">

Game Data

</div>

<div class="game">

Game Data

</div>

<div class="game">

Game Data

</div>

<div class="game">

Game Data

</div>

<div class="game">

Game Data

</div>
```

Comment: have you considered `jQuery.scroll()` in an interval loop?

Comment: Will look into it, but does that cover my two scenarios.

Comment: you'll need to check `element.scrollTop` and `element.height` to determine when you've reached the bottom, then do your redirect instead of continuing scrolling. I did something similar in an auto-scrolling article element

Comment: Does it have a way to find the last piece of content that I am wanting to show at the top of the page on the next scroll?

Comment: I think you'll need to post some HTML to better answer that